# Mapbox token works in Local env, but not in QA env

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, next.js, mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl

**Current Setup**

I load my Mapbox access token into my `next.js` app as `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_TOKEN`. The token is stored in my `.env.local` file as `NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_TOKEN` and also in the `s3` QA server config.

**Problem**

The Mapbox token is read when I'm in local development and loads the map, but when I visit the live QA link, it isn't read and the map doesn't load.

*What are the possible causes for this problem?*

Answer (score 0):

.env.local contains environment variables that are specific to your local machine.

You can define them .env or .env.production...

Check this for more information.

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables

Comment: I've already checked the link you sent me before and based on that I prefixed my token with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`. I don't want to expose any mapbox tokens inside of `.env.*` (except for `.env.local` when developing local).

Comment: The solution was to add the mapbox token as a build time variable in `s3`.

Comment: @ZackCarlson Feel free to add the solution you found as an answer to your own question.